# ¿Cómo consumir web services del SRI Ecuador con php?

Tags: php, xml, webservice

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$url = 'https://celcer.sri.gob.ec/comprobantes-electronicos-ws/RecepcionComprobantesOffline?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($url);
$directorio = "C:/Users/Adan Gimenez/Documents/FIRMADOS"; 
$fichero = "0505202001170756230000110010010000000091234567819.xml";
$decodeContent = base64_encode(file_get_contents($directorio."/".$fichero)); 
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ec.gob.sri.ws.recepcion">
              <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                <ns1:validarComprobante>
                  <xml>'.$decodeContent.'</xml>
                </ns1:validarComprobante>
              </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'; 
$parametros = new stdClass();
$parametros->xml = $xml;
$result = $client->validarComprobante($parametros);
print_r($result);
```

Pero me arroja este error:

> stdClass Object ( [RespuestaRecepcionComprobante] => stdClass Object ( [estado] => DEVUELTA [comprobantes] => stdClass Object ( [comprobante] => stdClass Object ( [claveAcceso] => N/A [mensajes] => stdClass Object ( [mensaje] => stdClass Object ( [identificador] => 35 [mensaje] => ARCHIVO NO CUMPLE ESTRUCTURA XML [informacionAdicional] => Se encontró el siguiente error en la estructura del comprobante: No se ha encontrado información en el tag claveAcceso. [tipo] => ERROR ) ) ) ) ) )

Se debe enviar al **web services** el **XML** codificado en `"base64_encode"` pero no sé que me falta, ya que sigue dando error. Agradecería alguna ayuda al respecto.

Comment: por lo que te dice el error, el xml no tiene un formato correcto. puedes publicar el contenido de `0505202001170756230000110010010000000091234567819.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

$decodeContent = file_get_contents($directorio."/".$fichero);

$parametros = new stdClass();

$parametros->xml = $decodeContent;

$result = $client->validarComprobante($parametros);

así debería ser.